# Programmatically register Appium server node with Selenium Hub

Tags: automated-tests, appium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to setup android parallel execution with help of multiple emulators and Selenium Grid.

For this I need to register Appium server node ( one for each of the emulators ) with Selenium Grid.

How to do this in Java?

I have did it through command line, now would like to automate end to end flow.

I could achieve appium server stand alone starting and stopping with below code

```
 private final static AppiumDriverLocalService service;

static {
System.out.println(APPIUM_HOST +"    "+ APPIUM_PORT + "     " + APPIUM_LOG_LEVEL + "     " + GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL );

    service = buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder().
                                             withIPAddress("127.0.0.1").
                                             usingPort(Integer.parseInt("4723"))
               .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
                   .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "info"));
}

public static void startAppiumServer() {
try{
             service.start();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void stopAppiumServer() {
    try{
                if (service.isRunning()) {
                     service.stop();
                }
    }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm not getting how to pass other parameters needed to register node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it working, please refer to https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-start-appium-service-by-appiumdriverlocalserivce/6324/25

but couple of questions still open for me

1. it didn't work with usingAnyFreePort(), I had to explicitly mention port number.
2. I could register android emulator node, even when it was not in open state, not sure if this is valid ?